# is it possible to use multiple groups with cvpartition in matlab?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, cross-validation

thank you in advance for the input.  I am using cvpartition to produce sets that I will use for training and validation on some data.  In particular I'm using

```
c = cvpartition(a,'kfold',5)
```

where a is a single group.  I would like to be able to generate training and testing sets using two groups, say a and b, rather than just a.  In other words I'm looking for something like this

```
c = cvpartition([a b],'kfold',5)  
%I haven't tried this; I would like to know ahead of time if this will work
```

Is this possible to do using cvpartition?  If not is there another way that I could easily do this without hard coding a solution?

Comment: Do you want to generate `5` partitions taken randomly out of the collection of groups ``a and b`` ? And do you have a specific type for your group ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a solution on my own.  Albeit not really my desired solution.  In my case a and b are integers so I divided a by 10 then added it to b to get a.b.  I then used this as my grouping variable.  In other words, I created a combined variable that encodes information from a and b, is one to one given a and b, and allows me to use cvpartition to the desired affect.